# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64 : two same variables in two different classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm coming from the java world, so my question may seem dumb.

Why the compiler complains when I have in two different implementation classes, the same variable (NSString object) name ?
Aren't they private by default ?
Is it forbidden ? Is there any build setting to change ?

After all, as I don't use here iVar, am I declaring this variable in C/C++ style ?

Example : 
SampleClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SampleClass : NSObject
{
...
}
@end
```

AnotherClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AnotherClass : NSObject
{
...
}
@end
```

SampleClass.m

```
#import "SampleClass.h"

@implementation SampleClass
NSString *myVar;

@end
```

AnotherClass.m

```
#import "AnotherClass.h"

@implementation AnotherClass
NSString *myVar;

@end
```

Compiler response about myVar variable :
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64

**EDIT :**
-1 ;((
World can be so intolerant...

**EDIT2**
Thanks for upvote ! There s still hope ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration is not declaring a variable as a member variable - it's declaring a global that happens to have been defined within an @implementation block.

If you want to define it as a **member variable** (or "instance variable" in Objective-C lingo), here's some information.

The general syntax of ObjC is:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    // member-variable declarations visible to everybody
}
// member-function declarations visible to everybody
@end
```

Your implementation should look like:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    // member-variable declarations visible to only you
}
// member-function definitions
@end
```

To make that a private **global variable,** you could do any of these options:

```
static NSString * variable = nil ; // note that this has to be a compile-time constant in Objective-C
```

In case you're not aware, the 'static' keyword says "internal linkage" - meaning it's not exposed to the linker as a variable that other files might want to access, so the linker won't even try to (and won't find duplicates of them).

Or you can rename your .m file to .mm ("Objective-C++"). You'll be forced to be more rigorous with coding (since now you're adhering to C++ standards instead of C), but you'll get to do things like this:

```
@implementation MyClass
namespace {
    NSString * myString = @"someString" ;
    NSString * myOtherString = someFunctionThatReturnsAString() ;
}
@end
```

Though I don't recommend the latter option until you're [a lot] more comfortable with C++.

Answer (score 4):

You are defining global variables (these are *not* variables on your classes!). To make them "private" to your file, use the `static` keyword:

```
static NSString *myVar;
```

If you instead want *instance variables*, you need to define them like this:

```
@implementation SampleClass {
    NSString *myVar;
}

@end
```

(Note the `{` and `}` after the `@implementation`.)